# Finding externalId with a Forge API without loading viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have been playing around with the C# DerivativesApi and I'm able to get model view meta data and properties. But I cannot find the externalId value. Is it possible to get this value without lodiang a viewer?

If the original model is from Revit this value contains the GUID of the element and it would be very useful for me to have easy access to this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now (April 2017) this information is only available on Viewer. We're currently investigating to have this exposed. A workaround is to download the Viewer JSON and extract the information.

Answer (score 0):

To add a little more precisions to what Augusto mentioned, you can use take a look at what [extract](https://extract.autodesk.io/) server is doing in [downloadBubble](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/blob/master/server/bubble.js#L39) and perform the same without viewer interaction. Once you downloaded the resources, you will find a *.db or *.sdb file which is an SQL lite database from where you can read mappings from dbIds to externalIds.

Unfortunately we don't have a sample that illustrates that workflow.

Hope that helps